# Geom_area() with discrete x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-area

I have the following dataset:

[image]

and I want a plot with PorcentajeElemento in the x-axis, PorcentajeNR in the y-axis, the colors according to UnidadAnatómica, but I would like to see it with different areas. So I have the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)

Dataset<- read.xlsx("porcentaje elemento.xlsx",rowNames=FALSE, colNames=TRUE, sheet="Los 
Cinchos")

ggplot(Dataset, mapping=aes(x=PorcentajeElemento, 
y=PorcentajeNR,fill=UnidadAnatómica),stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(rows=vars(Dataset$UnidadAnatómica))+
  geom_area(color=1,lwd=0.5,linetype=1)+
  theme_bw()
```

and I get the following plot:

[image]

As you can see, there is a mistake in the graph, and I guess that the reason is that x is "discrete". If I create another continuous variable (e.g. Dataset$B) for the x-axis, it works:

```
 ggplot(Dataset, mapping=aes(x=B, y=PorcentajeNR,fill=UnidadAnatómica),stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(rows=vars(Dataset$UnidadAnatómica))+
  geom_area(color=1,lwd=0.5,linetype=1)+
  theme_bw()
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

I want this last plot, but with Dataset$PorcentajeElemento in the x-axis. Is this possible?
Thank you

Comment: OP, there's a conceptual question with your plot:  how should "<10%" be represented?  This value in particular can only be represented discretely, since it offers a range of possible values (0-10%) vs. the others which are specifically numeric values.  Do you want to represent "<10%" as a number (ex. 0.10 or 10 %)?

Comment: Hi, I would like to represent it as a discrete variable, with "<10%" in the label of the x-axis. Thank you

Comment: Does it help to add `group=UnidadAnatómica` to the `aes()` function?

Comment: Yes! It worked with "group=UnidadAnatómica"! Thank you very much!